# How to insert white space after every number in python?

Tags: python, linux

I have a file with data like this

```
01000000000
00000010000
...

00000100000
10000000000
```

I want to convert it to

```
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
...

0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

How should I do it?

Thanks

Comment: How would you approach this problem in English? (AKA, 1. read contents from file, 2. iterate through contents and append space, etc)

Comment: `' '.join([i for i in line])` where `line` is each line of you file. You just need to check how to read a file line by line, and how to store strings into a file

Answer (score 0):

This snippet does it.

```
with open("path.txt", 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()

arr = []
for line in lines:
    arr.append(' '.join(line.strip()) + "\n")
    
print(arr)

with open("path.txt", 'w') as file:
    file.writelines(arr)
```

Comment: Be careful, this adds a space character at the end of each line (because linebreak `\n`  is considered a line character so it adds a space before in `join`). Rather do `arr.append(' '.join(line.strip()) + "\n")`

Comment: There is no need to do that actually. No element in `lines` list contains a linebreak at end. It is due to how the file is read.

Comment: So this is platform specific ?

Comment: Platform specific as in? I don't think any part of this code depends on what OS it is being executed on. It should work the same in any platform.

Comment: I agree, but I do get linebreaks in every line, which result in outputs lines like `0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 `  (notice the space at the end)  instead of `0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0`

Comment: Ah you're right from the beginning. I'll fix the snippet. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Read each line from the file removing any trailing whitespace. Use ' '.join() to intersperse spaces between each character. Save all the lines in a list.

Open the file for writing and output all lines from the list.

```
FILENAME = 'path.txt'

with open(FILENAME) as data:
    outlines = [' '.join(line) for line in map(str.rstrip, data)]

with open(FILENAME, 'w') as data:
    print(*outlines, sep='\n', file=data)
```